# Enabling multi language support for android application

Tags: android, localization, multilingual

I'm developing an android application which should support both English and Arabic.I have done
a. Created values folder for English and Arabic and updated the strings used.
b. Created an Application class for localization
c. Implemented the code on button click in Activity

See my Application file

**MyApp.java**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import java.util.Locale;
public class MyApp extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static void setLocaleAr (Context context){
        Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    }

    public static void setLocaleEn (Context context){
        Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    }
}
```

My activity class using button click

**MainActivity.java**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

    import java.util.Locale;

    public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

        // Splash screen timer
        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
        Button buttonEnglish,buttonArabic;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


            buttonEnglish =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnglish);
            buttonArabic =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonArabic);

            buttonEnglish.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttonArabic.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           switch(view.getId()) {
               case R.id.buttonEnglish:
                   MyApp.setLocaleEn(SplashActivity.this);
                   setLocale("en");
                   break;
               case R.id.buttonArabic: {
                   //buttonArabic.setBackground(getDrawable(R.color.white));
                   MyApp.setLocaleAr(SplashActivity.this);
                   setLocale("ar");
                   break;
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `needs restart or not` - have you tried it? And why don't you jus fall-back to the device's locale?

Comment: Is this the correct way of doing localisation for new versions also.  Now the localisation is not done with my code.

Comment: no, the correct way is to use system locale, and not set it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just forget everything and just implement the below code Snippet

Inside your build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig
 {
    resConfigs "en", "ar"
 }
```

And inside your activity:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
       switch(view.getId()) 
       {
           case R.id.buttonEnglish:

               updateLanguage("en");

               break;
           case R.id.buttonArabic: 

                updateLanguage("ar");

               break;
       }
    }

@Override
public void recreate()
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
    {
        super.recreate();
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(getIntent());
        finish();
    }
}

private void updateLanguage(String language)
{
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    SharedPreferences languagepref = getSharedPreferences("language",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = languagepref.edit();
    editor.putString("languageToLoad",language);
    editor.apply();

    recreate();
}
```

Comment: Got it.Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to recreate your activity.**

You can update locale from Splash Activity class itself, use this method to update locale

```
   //input: local values like "en","fr", "it"
   public void setLocale(String locale) {

     // Update Locale in App Configuration   
    getResources().getConfiguration().setLocale(new Locale(locale));
    getResources().updateConfiguration(getResources().getConfiguration(), getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


    // Restart Activity 
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(getIntent());
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

}
```