# Language change in Preference, showing dialog and restart app

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, settings, preference

In my app I have a setting fragment, this fragment implement a `onPreferenceChangeListerner` interface and lister only for a particular preference(is a ListPreference). In setting fragment, I could change the app's language, now I want to show a dialog to user to notice them if they change the language, the app will restart. User could select confirm or cancel.

```
 public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
       if(preference.getKey().equals("pref_language")){
            showLanguageChangeDialog();
       }
       return true;


private void showLanguageChangeDialog(final String newValue){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.string_language_change_dialog_title))
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.string_language_change_dialog_message))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.string_dialog_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Resources resources = SettingsFragment.this.getResources();
                        DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
                        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
                        switch (newValue){
                            case "English":
                                config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                                break;
                            case "German":
                                config.locale = Locale.GERMAN;
                                break;
                            case "Chinese":
                                config.locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        resources.updateConfiguration(config, dm);

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                SettingsFragment.this.restartApp();
                                return null;
                            }
                        }.execute();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.string_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .create().show();
        }



private void restartApp() {
            Intent i = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getActivity().getPackageName());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
```

Click "confirm" in the dialog to restart the app works well, but now I am facing some problems:

1. If the user click the "cancel", the language preference should not be changed, but actually it changed. How can I fix it? What I know is that if method `onPreferenceChange` return true, the preference will be updated, if false, not update. but how can I return false depends on the user's action.
2. The main thread won't wait for the result of Alertdialog. How can I wait for the result of alertdialog, so that I can decide which step to go on.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: There is no use to restart the app using intent just recreate the current activity or fragment.

Refer the below link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844810/enabling-multi-language-support-for-android-application/44846193#44846193

Comment: Thanks, but in my app, I need to fetch some data depends on the language, and other configurations should be changed too. So restarting the app is necessary.